# Visit frame once?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I was wondering if there is a code that can make flash recognize if a certain frame has already been visited. Is there a way to go about doing this? I was thinking about making a function that traces a frame when the player is already one it. I want the function to deny entrance to that frame after it was viewed once.

Comment: how about making an array of integers: unvisited frames and from your 'visit' event you just remove that frame int from the array and when you play/update frames you use only the frame numbers/ints from that array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In frame code (I assumes you're coding in frames):

```
var visited:Boolean;

if (visited) return;
visited = true;

//... do frame actions
```

Comment: Yes thanks, this helped to an extent. I put this code in the first frame and it recognized the boolean as true, but it counts it as the first view.

Answer (score 1):

Actionscript 3 doesn't care about frames. It's only flash that does.

So I would suggest keeping a global array of visited frames & populating it with frame numbers.

Answer (score 0):

How about disabling or removing the option to go to back to a completed frame? i.e if there is a back/forward button. Just go to the next page and disable or remove the back button. It's hard to give good advice without knowing what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  Setup an array of the same length as your movieclip in frames, all initialized to false.

```
var framesVisited:Array = [];

// since we're talking about frame numbers here, start at 1 instead of 0 like 
// you normally might.
for(var i:int = 1, ilen:int = this.totalFrames ; i <= ilen ; i++){
   framesVisited[i] = false;
}
```

Now, each time you visit a frame, make sure its corresponding array location is set to true.

```
framesVisited[this.currentFrame] = true;
```

Now in your function to check whether a frame has been visited, just return the value of the array.

```
public function hasFrameBeenVisited(frameNumber:int):Boolean{
    return Boolean(framesVisited[frameNumber]);
}
```